# Change of address in Google Search Console says an old domain no longer registered by me is moving to my new domain

Tags: google-search-console, domains, site-move

I did change of address in Google Search Console. The old domain has now expired and is registered by someone else, but I still see the notification that says the old domain is moving to my new domain.  How do I stop this?